# First appearance of a ghost after a person's death

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

In the ballet *Giselle*, the title character dies at the end of Act 1.

One wouldn't generally describe her ghostly presence in Act 2 as the result of a resurrection, because that implies that her death has been reversed or undone, and that is not the case in this narrative; yet I cannot think of another term that comes as close to describing her rising from the tomb into a new state of existence.

Is there a word for the appearance of a ghost as in this case?

Comment: *Reappearance* won't do?

Answer (score 20):

You might consider ***apparition***.  [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/apparition) defines it as:

> **apparition** (*n.*) an appearance, esp of a ghost or ghostlike figure

[Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/apparition) mentions:

> **apparition** (*n.*) That which appears or becomes visible; an appearance, especially of a remarkable or phenomenal kind.

Answer (score 11):

Ghosts and other post-mortem visitors are occasionally called *revenants*, from the present participle of French *revenir*, 'to return' , so the term ***revenance*** might be coined for a first (or indeed any) return.

Answer (score 6):

ODO's definition for [wraith](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wraith) reads:

> a ghost or ghostlike image of someone, especially one seen **shortly before or after their death.**

You can also consider using *spirit*, *spectre*, *phantom* or *phantasm* although they aren't necessarily restricted to first appearances.

**Edit:** I appear to have misread the question a little.

Giselle's "rising from the tomb into a new state of existence" could perhaps be described as a *discarnation*. The professional sounding *[U.S. Spiritist Medical Association](http://www.sma-us.org/content/death-and-discarnation-0)* describes *discarnation* in the following excerpt:

> We, as spiritists also need to differentiate between death and discarnation. Death is a biological phenomenon where the many organs and systems that maintain life collapse, progressively and irreversibly. **Discarnation, in turn, is the process of disconnection between the spirit and the physical body**, where the spirit gradually frees itself from the magnetic links that tied it to the matter, unleashing the fluidic bonds that united them. **Therefore, usually the process of discarnation begins after the biological phenomenon of death.** In turn, death is only definitive after the brainstem becomes inactive.

Webster provides a [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discarnate) and also does so for [disembodiment](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disembodiment).

I prefer StoneyB's *revenance* to either of the above.

Comment: I agree that discarnation is probably the most accurate conventional term but I like revenance better also. Thank you, people.

Comment: @juliancarter If you prefer StoneyB's answer, besides up-voting it, you can choose to _accept_ it by clicking on its associated tick/check mark.